# Allow kubernetes services through nginx (no ingress)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm deploying nginx as a container in a pod so that it can deny non-whitelisted traffic and reverse proxy to another container in the pod (can't use ingress controller for reasons). I need to whitelist other services in my cluster. I'd like to whitelist anything in the cluster but specific services is good.

What `allow` rules do I specify to let other services proxy through nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You can create isolation for your containers via [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/).

But please note:

Network policies are implemented by the network plugin, so you must be using a networking solution which supports `NetworkPolicy` - simply creating the resource without a controller to implement it will have no effect.

For example, you can use [Calico](https://github.com/projectcalico/cni-plugin) or [Weave](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/tree/master/plugin)